# Does class members occupy memory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, memory

A class is composed normally of member variables & methods. When we create instance of a class, memory is allocated for member variables of a class. Does member methods also occupy memory? Where are these methods stored?

Comment: Method implementations take up memory per Type (and I think per refinement with generics?) but this does *not* increase per object instance. E.g. `obj.GetType()` returns the Type which represents said methods (and a bunch of other things). The (instance) *variables* are per-instance, of course.

Comment: @pst, why post such good answer as comment?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov makes a fine point. I would have definitely up voted that and I answered this question myself with what I deem a pretty decent answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because it is only a small summary and incomplete :)

Comment: "No, declared methods do not take memory on a per-instance basis" is probably the simplest view here...

Comment: Class is just a template and saved as plain text inside .java file. Once it is instantiated, it takes space equal to memory variables space + pointers for class methods(both static and non-static).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public Person(string name)
   {
        Name = name;
   }

   public string SayName()
   {
      string hello = "Hello! My name is ";
      return hello + name;
   }
}

Person p = new Person("John");
string yourName = p.SayName();
```

The `SayName()` function goes on the `Call Stack`, and the `Person p` object and it's properties (`Name`) will stay in memory until the `Garbage Collection` comes in and cleans it up.

In terms of memory, you should be more concerned with the instance fields (properties) of the object, the amount of objects you are dealing with, and if your object is some time of `Reader` or `Connection`. If your object is a `Reader` or `Connection` you need to consider a `using` statement.

Pseudo-code:

```
using(DatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseConnection()
{
    // Process your calls and data
}
// The object is Disposable and it's resources are cleared
```

Comment: "The variables inside SayName(), which would be hello, only stay in memory while the function is in scope. So once the function completes, the variable is no longer in memory." Not entirely true, the GC can collect them as soon as the reference is no longer needed (and this includes `this`!)

Comment: Yes. This is true. I guess I should have made it more clear in terms of access.

Comment: "some time [sic] of `Reader` or `Connection`" - simply generalising to `IDisposable` is probably clearer, IMO

Answer (score 0):

Class s just a blue print, It doesn't occupy any space as long as variable of type class has not defined. Once the object/instance of type class is define, the class member will occupy some space in memory.
And the size of instance is equal to the sum of the size of members define in class.