# Do methods take up space in the class instance on javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

[Similar questions for other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11166956/1233788).

Consider a simple class:

```
class Foo {
  a;

  constructor(value) {
    this.a = value;
  }

  bar() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}
```

For each instance of this class, in javascript, will be consumed memory for a reference for `bar` method?

If I add other methods in `Foo` class, the instance of it will be heavier on memory?

If I need to create a lot of `Foo` objects, should I write:

```
function Foo(value) {
  this.a = value;
}

function bar(fooInstance) {
  console.log(fooInstance.a);
}
```

The questions above only illustrate the same question:
**Do methods take up space in the class instance?**

Comment: If you had changed it to `bar = () => { console.log(this.a); }`, then for each `instance` of `Foo`, there would be memory allocated for `Bar`. As written, there is only one method, on the prototype of the `Foo` class, which would get called by each instance. IE `const foo = new Foo(); console.log(foo.bar === foo.prototype.bar)` should be true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class methods are properties of the class prototype object, not each instance. Each instance just has a reference to its prototype, and the prototype has a reference to its parent class prototype, and so on.

Properties are found by searching the prototype chain; this is how inheritance works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
class Foo {
  a;

  constructor(value) {
    this.a = value;
  }

  bar() {
    console.log(this.a);
  }
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```js
function Foo(value) {
  this.a = value;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function () {
  console.log(this.a);
}

let foo1 = new Foo('foo1');
let foo2 = new Foo('foo2');

foo1.bar();
foo2.bar();

// true only if foo1.bar and foo2.bar reference the same object
console.log(foo1.bar === foo2.bar);
```

So there is only one *bar* method on the constructor's public prototype. It's "inherited" by instances of *Foo* via their private `[[Prototype]]` property that points to *Foo.prototype*.